# wp_head filter not executed inside custom class

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, filters, actions

I have this code in a simple plugin that is supposed to make wordpress unbranded:

```php
<?php 

/*
* Class to remove wp-* branding from WordPress
* @package users-manager.php
*/

class WpUnbrand {

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'remove_wp_header_links'));
        add_action('init', array($this, 'remove_wp_default_jquery'));
    }

    public function remove_wp_header_links()
    {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2);
        remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3);
        remove_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
        remove_action('wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
        remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0);
    }

    public function remove_wp_default_jquery()
    {
        if( !is_admin() ){
            wp_deregister_script('jQuery');
            wp_register_script( 'jQuery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js', false, false);
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery' );
        }
    }

}

new WpUnbrand();

?>
```

At the moment the plugin is in development so I didn't added the needed headers and I'm calling it inside another plugin like a component of the other plugin. I want to make is an indipendent plugin, but I've noticed that the `wp_head` isn't called. Is there something wrong into the code?

Answer (score 0):

If it is your actual code, you have hook to wp_head commented:

```
//add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'remove_wp_header_links'));
```

Just remove slashes and it should work.

```
add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'remove_wp_header_links'));
```

Comment: I've commented the hook to continue the plugin development. Also if it's uncommented, it will be not fired and inspecting using chrome console will show me into the `<head>` tag all the stuff that wordpèress will add

Comment: Did you try to change priority? You can't remove actions that wasn't created before. 

So you can try for example this call:
add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'remove_wp_header_links'), 20); To be sure your function will be called later.

Comment: need to test, not tried to give a major priority. I'll let you know. Thanks